# Keep Rows of Pandas Columns That Only Meet Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a dataframe that I only want to keep a row from if it is in a specific cluster AND has a value from another column in it.  This should be simple but not sure the best way of doing this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'name': ['Bobby','Diane','Joe','Bobby','Diane','Joe','Bobby','Diane'],
     'cluster':[2,4,1,1,2,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I want to remove all the rows that have the same cluster id that DON'T contain the name Diane within that cluster.
Desired output would be the rows with cluster id 1 removed because Diane is not in that cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `filter` with `groupby`

```
out = df.groupby('cluster').filter(lambda x : x['name'].isin(['Diane']).any())
    name  cluster
0  Bobby        2
1  Diane        4
4  Diane        2
5    Joe        4
7  Diane        6
```

Or `isin`

```
df.loc[df.cluster.isin(df.loc[df.name=='Diane','cluster'])]
    name  cluster
0  Bobby        2
1  Diane        4
4  Diane        2
5    Joe        4
7  Diane        6
```

Comment: Thanks!! Which one is faster?  Running this on millions of records.

Comment: @acodejdatam My 2nd method with isin should be faster ~

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` and then `filter` to keep only those clusters that contain `Diane`:

```
df.groupby('cluster').filter(lambda g: 'Diane' in g['name'].tolist())
```

Output:

|  | name | cluster |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bobby | 2 |
| 1 | Diane | 4 |
| 4 | Diane | 2 |
| 5 | Joe | 4 |
| 7 | Diane | 6 |

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP commented about speed concerns, here are the timings for the proposed solutions. The `loc` solution seems fastest:

```py
>>> %timeit df.groupby('cluster').filter(lambda g: 'Diane' in g['name'].tolist())
4.11 s ± 611 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
>>> %timeit df.groupby('cluster').filter(lambda x : x['name'].isin(['Diane']).any())
4.56 s ± 520 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
>>> %timeit df.loc[df.cluster.isin(df.loc[df.name=='Diane', 'cluster'])]
1.53 s ± 271 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The testing `df` for reference:

```py
>>> np.random.seed(238)
>>> names = np.random.choice(['Bobby', 'Diane', 'Joe'], size=int(1e7))
>>> clusters = np.random.choice(range(10), size=int(1e7))
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': names, 'cluster': clusters})
          name  cluster
0          Joe        1
1          Joe        4
...        ...      ...
9999998  Bobby        3
9999999  Diane        9

[10000000 rows x 2 columns]
```